# Laravel 5.8 add data to a layout variable via controller constructor

Tags: laravel, variables, view

I am trying to add data to a layout variable via a controller constructor. The reason I want to do this is because I always need to add categories to the topmenu when this controller is called.

No success so far. I add data to a layout via a view composer like this.

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Menu;

class MenuComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        if (in_array($view->getName(), ['layouts.master', 'layouts.master-post', 'layouts.error']))
        {
            $menu = Menu::menu('topmenu');

            view()->with('topmenu',  $menu);
            // view()->share('topmenu',  $menu); not working either
        }
    }
}
```

I want to extend the data in a Controller constructor.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Post;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class PostController extends Controller {
    public function __construct(View $view)
    {
        $view->offsetGet('topmenu');
        // $view->gatherData() not working either
    }
```

Whatever I try, Laravel throws an exception:

Target [Illuminate\Contracts\View\Engine] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Post\PostController, Illuminate\View\View].

Comment: Even if this did not error though, all you would be doing is getting the service container to  resolve you a View instance and calling something on it. It would not effect the views you return from your controller.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve, since it is not coming across clearly (to me) in the code?

Comment: add more data and try to be clear, it's not clear to me what is this and what you try to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the serviceprovider boot function:

```
view()->share('topmenu', [
    'items' => $newItemsToAdd
]);
```

In the viewComposer I did:

```
$extraItems = view()->shared('topmenu');

if (!empty($extraItems)) {
    $items = aray_merge($items, $extraItems);
}
```

}